# Excel SUMIFS on single criteria with zero and non-zero values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out a formula for SUMIFS where a multi-criteria range may or may not contain zero. Take the following table for example.

```
|Title    |Age|Color
|---------|---|------
|Odyssey  |5  |Brown
|Tempest  |2  |Yellow
|Iliad    |3  |
|Macbeth  |9  |Brown
```

My goal is to get a SUMIFS where Color is 'Brown' or blank. What I've tried is

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5,{"Brown",""})
```

However, this returns a value of '14' which is a sum of Brown values only and does not sum the '3' from the blank color row. If I switch it up and use

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5,{"","Brown"})
```

it returns '3' which is just the blank value, and not Brown. It seems to only consider the first value in the array.

What am I doing wrong? What's the correct formula for taking an array where the value can be NULL or a specified value?

PS I've also tried `ISBLANK`, `ISNULL`, `NULL`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap it in a sumproduct so it gives the sum of the sums

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5,{"Brown",""}))
```

otherwise it doesn't recognise the values in curly brackets as an array and just looks at whichever you put first.

Comment: =SUM(SUMIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5,{"Brown",""})) Also works the same. Essentially it has to be wrapped in a function that recognizes the array.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out what I was doing wrong:

Need to encapsulate the entire formula in a SUM() function.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5,{"Brown",""}))
```

Comment: Yes, it needs to be wrapped in a function that recognizes the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by summing two regular `SUMIF` functions like this:
`=SUMIF(C2:C5,"Brown",B2:B5)+SUMIF(C2:C5,"",B2:B5)`. This yields (5 + 9) + (3) = 17.

For large datasets this is [allegedly faster](https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-if-equal-to-either-x-or-y) than `SUMPRODUCT`.

```
   A        B    C
1|Title    |Age|Color
 |---------|---|------
2|Odyssey  |5  |Brown
3|Tempest  |2  |Yellow
4|Iliad    |3  |
5|Macbeth  |9  |Brown
```

Comment: Absolutely but where's the elegance in that? :) Appreciate the input, though.

Comment: @Dezzie Tastes are different of course :D But I would probably prefer this solution myself. Why? One function instead of two seems "elegant" and the logic is simpler without the need to wrap functions in other functions. See also my edit regarding speed.

Comment: @Dezzie By the way: I've scratched my head over this problem before, and I never seem to remember the right syntax without a refresher. The "most elegant" solution should maybe be the intuitive one? I think many people, including myself, would try exactly the formula that you attempted first..!